# How to apply animation on cached image in Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I want to show the image using Glide animation. I'm downloading this image from the server. The animation is working fine when it downloads from the server but it's not working when the image is taken from Glide cache

```
requestOptions.skipMemoryCache(true);
requestOptions.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);
```

Please check my code below

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.timeout((int) NetworkParam.CONNECTION_TIME_OUT);
requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.img_blue_shirt);
requestOptions.priority(Priority.HIGH);
requestOptions.signature(new ObjectKey(String.valueOf(imgName)));
//requestOptions.skipMemoryCache(true);
requestOptions.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE);

//requestOptions.error(R.drawable.img_blue_shirt);
try {
    Glide.with(imageView.getContext().getApplicationContext())
         .load(imgUrl)
         .transition(GenericTransitionOptions.with(R.anim.anim_slide_in_left))
         .apply(requestOptions)
         .into(imageView);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean cached on disk or in memory?

Comment: Its stored in Glide cache but how can i use animation on image which is coming from cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes I got my answer here we cant apply animation on cached image in glide for more info please check below link

https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/transitions.html

Answer (score 13):

According to the documentation [here](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/transitions.html#custom-transitions), in Glide v4 you can implement and apply a custom `TransitionFactory`.

For always crossfading, in Kotlin you can:

1. Implement the `TransitionFactory` interface

```
class DrawableAlwaysCrossFadeFactory : TransitionFactory<Drawable> {
  private val resourceTransition: DrawableCrossFadeTransition = DrawableCrossFadeTransition(300, true) //customize to your own needs or apply a builder pattern
  override fun build(dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Transition<Drawable> {
    return resourceTransition
  }
}
```

2. Apply it as a transition

```
GlideApp.with(this)
  .load(url)
  .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.with(DrawableAlwaysCrossFadeFactory()))
  .into(image)
```

Answer (score 7):

To apply image change transition in glide 4.10 use

```
Glide.with(this).load(artwork)
                            ..transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                            .into(playerBackground);
```

Comment: The question is about animation on cached images, and this solution doesn't help with them.

Answer (score 1):

> By default, Glide will not animate the image when loading it. If
>   images are cached on disk, Glide will animate. To change that, define
>   a custom TransitionFactory and pass it in with
>   DrawableTransitionOptions.

For an example implementation, see the cross fade factory: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/request/transition/DrawableCrossFadeFactory.java