# How do load images in Glide with Animation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-glide

I am using glide to load image from server image and it is showing suddenly without any animation. I need to display the image with fading animation, please give me some suggestions on this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use `transitions()` API in the GLIDE builder call. Here are 2 possible ways you can achieve this.

1) By using transitions API : [Official Documentation](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-placeholders-fade-animations)

```
GlideApp  
.with(context)
.load(....)
.transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade()) //Here a fading animation
.into(....);
```

2) By creating a `TransitionFactory` : [SOF Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54983155/1149398) by user [tudor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3758089/tudor)

```
 GlideApp.with(this)
  .load(url)
  .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.with(Your_custom_factory))
  .into(image)
```

Hope this helps